Display an image with its size in tkinter
I have an 1920x1080 image and I want to display it in an window using tkinter, I created an 1920x1080 window and added the image, the image show up an scaled image instead of its 1920x1080 size.
This is my code:
accountSystem = Tk()

accountSystem.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
accountSystem.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
accountSystem.geometry('1920x1080')
accountSystem.title('ACCOUNT SYSTEM')

signin_bgImage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'images/sign_in.jpg')
signin_bgLabel=Label(sign_in, image = signin_bgImage)
signin_bgLabel.place(x=0, y=0) 

accountSystem.resizable(0,0)

accountSystem.mainloop()




What happens if you create a larger window? Also can you show us a minimal version of the code which still exhibits the issue>

Can you add your code as a part of your question, so that it keeps its formatting.

Did you check your scale settings for the display?  Some default settings are greater than 100%.

yeah that's the reason why. I've changed my scale and it works fine. Thank you so much for your help.
